# Mongodb C# driver with ignoreNull and ignore bool default values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

It is impossible to set ignoreNull and ignoreDefault together.
Is it possible to set ignore all nulls and boolean false values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are mutually exclusive.  You shouldn't need to set both of these at the same time as a property will only have 1 default value.  For reference types, it's null and for value types its a value (bool, for instance, is false).  You should be able to set IgnoreIfDefault and be fine.